# Testing assertion with value and response time - Karate

Tags: karate, bdd, gherkin

I try to compare the response time with certain amount of time, but I don't know how to do it. I dont even know if the number I give is taken as seconds or milliseconds

This is my code:

Scenario: Case
Given url 'https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2'
When method GET
Then print responseTime
* def time = response.data.responseTime
And assert response.data.responseTime < 10

The response:

[image: 1]

I've also tried putting the numbers like milliseconds, but get the same result :(

Comment: read this please: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me, try it. It is milliseconds:

```
* url 'https://httpbin.org/get'
* method get
* assert responseTime < 2000
```

Refer docs: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#responsetime

That said, I personally don't recommend this kind of assertions in your tests. That's what performance testing is for: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/tree/master/karate-gatling